# How do I go to the last item in Kotlin listOf using a previous button?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to learning Kotlin in Android Studio. I am working on a quiz app that has 20 questions, I am able to click next to the last question and then the questions start back at question 1. However, the part I am struggling with is the previous button. Every attempt leads to my android app crashing. I have put the latest code I've tried below. Thank you in advance!

```
 private val questionBank = listOf(
    Question(R.string.question_1, false),
    Question(R.string.question_2, true),
    Question(R.string.question_3, true),
    Question(R.string.question_4, false),
    Question(R.string.question_5, false),
    Question(R.string.question_6, true),
    Question(R.string.question_7, false),
    Question(R.string.question_8, true),
    Question(R.string.question_9, false),
    Question(R.string.question_10, false),
    Question(R.string.question_11, false),
    Question(R.string.question_12, true),
    Question(R.string.question_13, false),
    Question(R.string.question_14, true),
    Question(R.string.question_15, false),
    Question(R.string.question_16, false),
    Question(R.string.question_17, true),
    Question(R.string.question_18, false),
    Question(R.string.question_19, false),
    Question(R.string.question_20, true))

private var questionIndex = 0


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.previous_button).setOnClickListener(){
        questionIndex = (questionIndex--)

       if (questionIndex > 0) {
            questionIndex--
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_question).setText(questionBank[questionIndex].resourceID)
       }
        else {
           questionIndex = (questionIndex - 1) % 20
           findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_question).setText(questionBank[questionIndex].resourceID)

       }
    }
    findViewById<Button>(R.id.next_button).setOnClickListener {
        updateView()
    }
}

private fun updateView() {
    questionIndex = (questionIndex + 1) % 20
    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_question).setText(questionBank[questionIndex].resourceID)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about modelling the questions as a stack like so:

```
data class Question(val resourceId: Int, val answer: Boolean)

val questions = listOf(
        Question(R.string.question_1, false),
        Question(R.string.question_2, true),
        Question(R.string.question_3, true),
        Question(R.string.question_4, false),
        Question(R.string.question_5, false),
        Question(R.string.question_6, true),
        Question(R.string.question_7, false),
        Question(R.string.question_8, true),
        Question(R.string.question_9, false),
        Question(R.string.question_10, false),
        Question(R.string.question_11, false),
        Question(R.string.question_12, true),
        Question(R.string.question_13, false),
        Question(R.string.question_14, true),
        Question(R.string.question_15, false),
        Question(R.string.question_16, false),
        Question(R.string.question_17, true),
        Question(R.string.question_18, false),
        Question(R.string.question_19, false),
        Question(R.string.question_20, true)
)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val questionStack = Stack<Question>()

    questionStack.push(questions.first())

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.previous_button).setOnClickListener  {
        if (questionStack.isNotEmpty()) {
            questionStack.pop()
            if (questionStack.isNotEmpty()) {
                questionStack.peek().also { previousQuestion ->
                    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_question).setText(previousQuestion.resourceId)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.next_button).setOnClickListener {
        if (questionStack.size + 1 <= questions.size) {
            questionStack.push(questions.elementAt(questionStack.size))
            questionStack.peek().also { nextQuestion ->
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text_question).setText(nextQuestion.resourceId)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This means you can get rid of the `questionIndex` variable and all code associated with updating it. Also, a stack is a good way of modelling a simple linear forward/backward flow, when the user presses back, you pop the stack and the previous question is now the question on top of the stack. When the user presses next, you push the next question onto the stack and that is the new current question. Obviously you need to do a bit of sanity checking before peeking/popping the stack (but that's included in my answer above).

Comment: A `Stack` is a very old class and is no longer recommended to use in their own [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html). Instead you could use an `ArrayDeque<Question>()`.

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't know that